# Unable to estimate AR(p) coefficients and $\sigma^2$

Tags: time-series, estimation, autoregressive, estimators

I am currently trying to solve this problem pertaining to the Yule-Walker equations:

Let $\{X_t\}_{t\in Z}$ be a causal autoregressive process given by $$X_t = \varphi X_{t−2} +W_t$$ with $\{W_t\}_{t\in Z} \sim WN(0, \sigma^2)$.
Assume that the following sample moments were obtained
after observing $X_1, \dots, X_{200}$: $b\gamma(0) = 6$ and $b\rho(2) = 0.5%$.
(Remember the notation $\gamma(0) = \text{Var}(X_t)$ and $\rho(2) = \text{corr}(X_t,X_{t−2}).)$
By using the causal assumption, find the method of moments estimates for the parameters $\varphi$ and $\sigma^2$.

No, up until now, I have been using the 2 Yule-Walker equations and I have gotten equations for both $\varphi$ coefficients and the $\sigma^2$ in terms of the sample autocorrelation at lag 1. Can anyone please help me with this, as I have been trying to solve this for over a week now?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to re-label the time units so that the unit of time equals 2. Then things become easier. Let `$X^{*}_{t} = X_{2t}$ and
$W^{*}_t = W_{2t} ~\forall~t = 0,1,2,3, \ldots \infty$, Then, you can rewrite the autoregressive process as the AR(1) below: It's the same model as the one you wrote except that the time unit is doubled.

$X^{*}_t = \phi X^{*}_{t-1} + W^{*}_t$

Once you have it as an AR(1), the Yule Walker equations should be more straightforward.